# Passing a angled bracket as a command-line argument input while debugging

Tags: gdb, command-line-arguments, io-redirection

I'm writing a brainfuck interpreter in NASM, where code is supplied as a command line argument to the program. I'm trying to test looping, but GDB doesn't like my input. For example, this executes error-free when run on its own:

```
$./interpret "+++++[->+<]"
```

It hangs indefinitely, but I think that that's due to a bug in the looping logic in the interpreter (thus GDB).

If I load `interpret` into GDB though and attempt to supply the same argument, I get complaints:

```
gef➤  start "+++++[->+<]"
/bin/bash: line 1: ]: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: line 1: ]: No such file or directory
```

This seems to be due to `<` being interpreted as redirection despite the quotes, since `[]` works fine in GDB.

I tried escaping the STDIN redirection with `\<`, but that leads to the same error, and `<<`, but that leads to a warning:

```
gef➤  start "+++++[->+<<]"
/bin/bash: line 1: warning: here-document at line 1 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `]')
```

And the code gets cut off:

```
$r15   : 0x00007fffffffe428  →  0x002d5b2b2b2b2b2b ("+++++[-"?)
```

Is there a way to have GDB take what I give literally to `start`, and not attempt to do any redirection/interpretation of the arguments?

Comment: Surprisingly (to me), `echo "+++++[->+<]" > bfcode` then `start $(cat bfcode)` works as a workaround. I would have expected that to be the same, but apparently not. It's especially confusing since `start $(echo "+++++[->+<]") doesn't work, which I'd also expect to be equivalent. I'd still like a way of supplying the argument directly though since needing to save to file first complicates testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to have GDB take what I give literally to start, and not attempt to do any redirection/interpretation of the arguments?

GDB isn't doing any interpretation, `bash` does. Using single-quotes instead of double-quotes may fix that.

(I wasn't able to replicate the problem using GDB-10.0 and bash-5.1.4 with double quotes though.)

Comment: I wonder if GEF is doing something then. The behavior is definitely different inside GDB than it is outside. I'm also pretty sure I tried single quotes. Thanks, I'll try it again.

Comment: Turns out it is something that GEF is doing. If I disable GEF it works fine with single quotes.